# Java: Finding Line Breaks after Splitting by Space

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is any way to detect line breaks after I have split a string by a different delimiter.

For example:

```
int lineCounter = 1;
String originalString = "Hello World! \n Every day is a \n good day if you have \n pizza";
String[] dividedString = originalString.split("\\s");

// Loop through the divided string and print the tokens
for(int i=0; i<dividedString.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(dividedString[i] + " found on line #" + lineCounter);

   //Pseudo Code // This is where I need help
   if(newline is found)
      lineCounter++;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

\s regex contains \n too with any others, so if you split the String by it and examine the result array, you can't say where were \n before. 
 You can examine only the original String, I think.

Comment: That makes sense.
I was getting some weird results before, where three separate but empty strings were found at the end of each line.  Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it using

```
originalString.split(" ");
```

It splits the \n also into separate strings and then for lineCount you can use the condition

```
dividedString[i].equals("\n")
```